# Deep Learning Toolbox - Deep Belief Network

Tags: matlab, deep-learning

I'm currently trying to run the matlab code from the deeplearntoolbox, which is the `test_example_DBN.m`.

However it encountered some error, which i do not understand what the problem is and how to fix it. Need your help to explain and teach me where the problem is and how to make it work. Thanks in advance..

The error message as below:

> ??? Attempted to access lmisys(5); index out of bounds because
>   numel(lmisys)=4.
>
> Error in ==> lmiunpck at 23
>
> rs=lmisys(4); rv=lmisys(5);  % row sizes of LMISET,LMIVAR
>
> Error in ==> nnsetup at 26
>
> [LMI_set,LMI_var,LMI_term,data]=lmiunpck(lmisys);
>
> Error in ==> dbnunfoldtonn at 10
>
> nn = nnsetup(size);
>
> Error in ==> TryDBN at 31
>
> nn = dbnunfoldtonn(dbn, 10);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because DeepLearnToolBox has an NeuralNetwork tool which is conflict with the Matlab own NN toolbox.So you can solve this as following:

Click File-SetPath-Add With Subfolders,select your toolbox path. Make sure the path of DeepLearnToolBox is in the top.After that ,try again.

Answer (score -1):

You need to copy all *.m* files of the **DeepLearnToolBox** to your Matlab Path via `SetPath'.